# subprocess error on windows while listing an s3 bucket

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to list the contents of an s3 bucket using Python 2.7.13. This does not work:

```
>>> args
['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://mybucket']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Why is this so ?

But this works:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Why is `shell=False` failing but `shell=True` working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are totally right to try to use `subprocess` with `shell=False`. It is the best way to ensure portability, and is probably faster to launch.

In your case, your arguments look okay (no redirection, no pipe, multiple command):

```
['aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://mybucket']
```

so the only thing that prevents it to work with `shell=False` is the fact that `aws` is not really an executable, but rather a file whose extension (not shown here) is contained in `PATHEXT`

On my machine `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY`

Means that any `aws.js`, `aws.bat`, ... file can be executed. But you need the shell for that.

To locate your program, type `where aws` in a command prompt, you'll get the full path & extension of the command.

If you don't want to use `shell=True`, there's an alternative which amounts to the same thing

```
args = ['cmd','/c','aws', 's3', 'ls', 's3://mybucket']
```

Since you're already running a `cmd` you don't need `shell=True`